# azure/msal-angular not redirecting to home component after login success in angular 6

Tags: azure-active-directory, angular6, azure-ad-msal

I'm using msal-angular(1.0.0) and msal(^1.3.0). After successful login, page is empty and not redirecting to home page. But when i refresh the page it shows the home page content.

I followed this : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular/v/1.0.0

In my application when login success user should be redirected to home page.

```
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate : [MsalGuard] },
{ path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, },
{ path: '',
redirectTo: 'home',
pathMatch: 'full'
}
```

I tried with @azure/msal-angular - 0.1.4 as well
How to redirect to home page without refreshing?

Comment: The below code may help you const routes: Routes = [{
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    canActivate: [
      MsalGuard
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];

Comment: Thanks for response Sruthi. That didnt work :-(

Answer (score 0):

Hi This will not work in this case.
Try this:

```
    msal:loginSuccess, () => {
this.router.navigate(['/home'])
}
```

Comment: this code does not work at all, actually le HomeCompenent is instantiated twice… not good..

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example of angular with azure ad/msal https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-angular/blob/6ea2a37027c787bd19b8b57a58cbb1c46a5a6ef0/src/app/app-routing.module.ts

i linked directly to the routing page, its exactly as sruthi says, but login success should bring you to where you were trying to reach before you clicked login. as per sruthis routing, if you were at site root, it should redirect you to home .

In your code above, the routing is not right, why did you secure the home but not the profile? also, as per your routing setup in your code, the second you load the page, you will get bumped to the login page. along with homecomponent.